# Stream reasoning / Reactive programming in prolog?

Tags: stream, prolog, reactive-programming, swi-prolog, event-driven

I was wondering if you know of any way to use prolog for stream processing, that is, some kind of reactive programming, or at least to let a query run on a knowledge base that is continuously updated (effectively a stream), and continuously output the output of the reasoning?

Anything implemented in the popular "prologs", such as SWI-prolog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Logtalk's support for event-driven programming to define monitors that watch for knowledge base update events and react accordingly. You can run Logtalk using most Prolog systems as the backed compiler, including SWI-Prolog.

The event-driven features are described e.g. in the user manual:
http://logtalk.org/manuals/userman/events.html

The current distribution contains some examples of using events and monitors. An interesting one considering your question is the `bricks` example:
https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/bricks

Running this example first and then looking at its code should give you as good idea of what you can do with system wide events and monitors.

Answer (score 4):

XSB has stream processing capabilities. See page 14 in the

[XSB Manual](http://xsb.sourceforge.net/manual2/manual2.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! Would be great if you could provide a some example code on how to use this? :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on something related, in project [pqConsole](https://github.com/CapelliC/pqConsole) already there is the basic capability: report to the user structured data, containing actionable areas (links) that call back in Prolog current state, hence the possibility to expose actions and react appropriately (hopefully).

It's strictly related to pqConsole::win_write_html, showcasing recent Qt capabilities of SWI-Prolog.

Here an example of a snippet producing only a simple formatted report, I'll try now to add the reactive part, so you can evaluate if you find expressive this basic system. Hints are welcome...

```
/*  File:    win_html_write_test.pl
    Author:  Carlo,,,
    Created: Aug 27 2013
    Purpose: example usage win_html_write/1
*/

:- module(win_html_write_test,
      [dir2list/1
      ]).

:- [library(http/html_write)].
:- [library(dirtree)].

dir2list(Path) :-
    dirtree(Path, DirTree),
    % sortree(compare_by_attr(name), DirTree, Sorted), !,
    DirTree = Sorted,
    phrase(html([\css,
             \logo,
             hr([]),
             ul(\dirtree2html(Sorted, [])),
             br([])]), Tokens),
    with_output_to(atom(X), print_html(Tokens)),
    win_html_write(X),
    dump_page_to_debug(X).

css --> html(style(type='text/css',
           ['.size{color:blue;}'
           ])).

logo --> html(img([src=':/swipl.png'],[])).

dirtree2html(element(dir, A, S), Parents) -->
    html(li([\elem2html(A),
         ul(\elements2html(S, [A|Parents]))])).
dirtree2html(element(file, A, []), _Parents) -->
    html(li(\elem2html(A))).

elem2html(A) -->
    {memberchk(name=N, A),
     memberchk(size=S, A)
    },
    html([span([class=name], N), ' : ', span([class=size], S)]).

elements2html([E|Es], Parents) -->
    dirtree2html(E, Parents),
    elements2html(Es, Parents).
elements2html([], _Parents) --> [].

dump_page_to_debug(X) :-
    open('page_to_debug.html', write, S),
    format(S, '<html>~n~s~n</html>~n', [X]),
    close(S).
```

This snippet depends on [dirtree](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=dirtree), that should be installed with

```
?- pack_install(dirtree).
```

*edit* With 3 modifications now the report has the ability to invoke editing of files:

- call to get paths in structure

```
    dir2list(Path) :-
        dirtree(Path, DirTreeT),
        assign_path(DirTreeT, DirTree),
        ...
```

- request a specialized output for files only

```
    dirtree2html(element(file, A, []), _Parents) -->
        html(li(\file2html(A))).
```

- finally, the 'handler' - here just place a request to invoke the editor

```
    file2html(A) -->
        {memberchk(name=N, A),
         memberchk(path=P, A),
         memberchk(size=S, A)
        },
        html([span([class=name],
                   [a([href='writeln(editing(\'~s\')), edit(\'~s\')'-[N,P]], N)]
        ), ' : ', span([class=size], S)]).
```

and now the file names are clickable, write a message and get edited if requested: a picture

[image: after extending the report with links to editor]

Answer (score 2):

You should check out *RTEC: Run-Time Event Calculus*:

https://github.com/aartikis/RTEC

> RTEC is an open-source Event Calculus dialect optimised for stream reasoning. It is written in Prolog and has been tested under YAP 6.2.

Feature highlights:

> Interval-based.
>
> ---
>
> Sliding window reasoning.
>
> ---
>
> Interval manipulation constructs for non-inertial fluents.
>
> ---
>
> Caching for hierarchical knowledge bases.
>
> ---
>
> Support for out-of-order data streams.
>
> ---
>
> Indexing for handling efficiently irrelevant data.

There is also a mention of it on the SWI-Prolog website:

https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/file_details/prologmud_I7/prolog/ec_planner/RTEC/README.md

which presumably relies on:

https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/dialect/yap.pl

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this hasn't been brought up so far, but in SWI-Prolog there is [`prolog_listen`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=prolog_listen/2), which can, amongst other things, monitor dynamic updates to the database:

[image]